# Token matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, api, social-network-friendship

I am trying to set up a way to add friends on a social media type site, but something is wrong and I don't know what is going on.

Here is my model:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    #static variables for friend_status attribute
    FORMER_FRIENDS = 0
    FRIENDS = 1
    A_REQUESTS_B = 2
    B_REQUESTS_A = 3

    friend_A = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_A')
    friend_B = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_B')
    friend_status = models.IntegerField

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s and %s friendship' % (self.friend_A, self.friend_B)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('friend_A', 'friend_B'),)
```

Here is my URL:

```
 url(r'^friend_request/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)', AddFriend.as_view(), name = 'add_friend'),
```

Here is my class-based view:

```
class AddFriend(APIView):
def get(self, request, username):
    user = Token.objects.get(key='token string').user
    friend = User.objects.get(username=username)
    #check for friendship instance
    new_friend, created = Friend.get_or_create(friend_A=user, friend_B=friend)
```

When I try to access the endpoint I get the following output:

```
DoesNotExist at /friend_request/brian
Token matching query does not exist.
```

Setting up friend relationships is proving more difficult than I expected.  Please advise.

Comment: This token not match in `Token.objects.get(key='token string')`. Where you get `token string` ?. Its exists or not ?

Comment: Ngoc Pham, Sorry for the slow response, I just saw this. You are correct, the string 'token string' does not exist.  But how do I get the correct token string?  The token string is what I am trying to get from the user.  I don't know it beforehand.